# Can't record the screen with OBS Studio

Tags: windows, recording, screen-recorder, obs-studio

I have two screens and want to create a video of my work on Display 2.

[image: OBS Properties for 'Display Capture']

So, added a source 'Display Capture'. What happens is in neither of the displays I'm able to see. Added anyways, clicked "Start Recording" but was getting black screen.

I tested also:

- different sources, more precisely Window Capture (which doesn't suit my needs and sometimes works, sometimes doesn't and I didn't yet figure out why) and Game Capture (which never worked).
- "Run as Administrator" and faced the same result.
- Remove the HDMI cable and plug back in

Here is my last log file - https://obsproject.com/logs/gN1kPrBTngp0LIDH

---

### Edit

Just gone through [the following troubleshooting steps](https://obsproject.com/wiki/Laptop-Troubleshooting#configure-your-system-for-display-capture)

> **Display Capture for NVIDIA-based Laptops**
>
> 1. Close OBS if it is currently open
> 2. Go to the NVIDIA Control Panel by right clicking on your desktop, and then clicking on "NVIDIA Control Panel"
> 3. Click on "Manage 3D Settings" if it is not already selected Under the Program Settings tab, click the "Add" button under where it says
>      "Select a program to customize:"
> 4. Navigate to the .exe path for OBS and add it to the list Default paths are: C:\Program Files\obs-studio\bin\64bit\obs64.exe and
>      C:\Program Files (x86)\obs-studio\bin\32bit\obs32.exe)
> 5. Make sure it is selected in the drop down list
> 6. Then, under where it says "Select the preferred graphics processor for this program" open the drop down and select "Integrated graphics"
>      from the list
> 7. Save and apply, then open OBS and check Display Capture again

and still no success...

Comment: The log file seems alright with no major errors, did you try to tweak some settings?(encoder/hardware acceleration, etc).

Comment: I also removed the HDMI cable, inserted back in and restarted the computer.

Comment: When you added the Display Capture, did you resize it so it's just not a tiny pixel on the screen. Is it enabled/active? Are there any other things you're trying to display that it may be behind?

Comment: Yes it's active. About the little red dot, I see it but once clicking it automatically disappears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### TLDR; Settings > Graphics > Browse OBS > Options > Power Saving

1. Go to your **Windows Settings** (gear icon in the start menu)

   [image: Windows Settings]
2. Search for **Graphics Settings**

   [image: graphics settings]
3. Select **Desktop or Classic App**

   [image: graphics settings > desktop app]
4. Select **Browse** and find the `obs64.exe` path - which is typically located here:

   ```
   C:\Program Files\obs-studio\bin\64bit\obs64.exe
   ```

   [image: obs64.exe]
5. Go to the **Options**

   [image: OBS Options]
6. Set to **Power Savings**

   [image: Options > Power Savings]

Comment: The Display tab does not have a "graphics settings".

Comment: @pacoverflow go to Windows settings and search for "Graphic" and see if it comes up.  Worked for me in Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

The workaround I've used was to install the [TinyTake app](https://tinytake.com/) and was able to record the screen in a fast and easy way.

Comment: Doesn't really help with OBS though.  I'm using it for the virtual web cam.